# how to create aws iam role with console access and saml

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I have been looking at aws document here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp_saml.html

I am able to create a role with console access from aws console how do i achieve the same using aws cloudformation.

[image: This what i want to reflect in CFT]

I have created the cft here below but role does not work, look like it does not have console access.

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "SAMLID": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "SAML IDENTITY PROVIDER ARN"
    }
  },
    "Resources": {
      "FullAdminXME": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "Description" : "SAML Role for Azure AD SSO",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": 
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Federated": { "Ref" : "SAMLID" }
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
                "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                    "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
                  }
                }
              }

          },
          "ManagedPolicyArns": [
            "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"           
          ]
        }
      },
```

Comment: @user12027552 are there any errors you are receiving? Have you ensured that everything is correctly setup on the Azure AD side?

Comment: Cloud formation questions are on topic for Stack Overflow. It's even better if the question has programming involved. Is there a particular language you're targetting?

Comment: From Azure AD everything is fine the role i created with Console works but roles created with CFT don't work. @StefanCharsley

Comment: @GeorgeStocker yea i have pasted the code which is not working for me in JSON (JavaScript Programming Language)

Comment: @user12027552 can you expand on "roles created with CFT don't work"? Is the CFT template failing to create/update? Is there an error when trying to login to AWS using Azure AD? Does it login successfully but have no permissions?

Comment: @StefanCharsley CFT is created successfully but Roles are not provisioned in Azure. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/amazon-web-service-tutorial)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally After back and forth with AWS i was able to resolve above issue CFT was setup correctly only issues is of Role Name Character limit in Azure is 119 see below.

"The combined length of the role ARN and the saml-provider ARN for a role being imported must be 119 characters or less"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/amazon-web-service-tutorial